# New stuff on Meta!

Tags: discussion

We've reorganized some of the help-related material on Meta and other areas of OR.SE. In particular:

- We have a new "[what can I ask?](https://or.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)" page that is specific to OR.SE instead of generic
- We have created FAQ entries on Meta:

  - [How should I ask for help with my OR model?](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231/how-should-i-ask-for-help-with-my-or-model)
  - [Can I ask a homework question on OR.SE?](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229/can-i-ask-a-homework-question-on-or-se)
  - [What is a minimal, reproducible example (reprex), and how do I write one?](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191/what-is-a-minimal-reproducible-example-reprex-and-how-do-i-write-one)
  - [How do I use MathJax on this site?](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/how-do-i-use-mathjax-on-this-site)

Your comments and suggestions are welcome.

**Don't forget, Meta and [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94323/operations-research) are our spots for discussing the site.** Please feel free to join the conversation!